# Ability to locate existing solar panels with Google solar API?

Tags: google-solar-api

I've been looking into the buildingInsights endpoint of the Google Solar API, and was wondering if anyone knows if is is capable of returning whether a building has solar panels already installed on it. I was planning to create a project that uses maps of existing solar areas.

Comment: No, the API is geared towards solar potential, and so doesn't give any information about existing solar panels.